# Where's my seat belt buckle?

Tags: hyundai, seat-belt, i10

I'm driving a 2018 Hyundai I10. It's got three seats in the back, each with a seatbelt. But I can't find the middle seatbelt's buckle (not the tongue — I've found that — but the socket for it). Obviously I've looked between the seats and their backs, including lifting the middle seat forward, and in the hollow that holds the other seat's buckle, and have tried reaching into the seat backs. Does anyone know where it might be hiding?

Some pics (that link to larger versions):

[image: (picture of the center seat in the rear)]

[image: (picture of the center seat in the rear, when the seat is pulled up and forward)]

Comment: Daft question maybe, but the socket - is it designed to take two tongues? ie it has two slots...

Comment: If the three backseats are essentially one long bench seat, the "socket" for the middle seat's belt will often share an opening with the socket for one of the outer seats.

Comment: Literally take it back to the dealership (any Hyundai dealership) and have them find it for you. If it's actually missing, they'll have to put one in for you. I believe warranties are world wide, aren't they? If they find it, you're golden. More than likely it's hiding under the seat and you just haven't found it yet.

Comment: @sol I had checked that also. No dice. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: @mik thanks. That's what I meant by "hollow" in the question. (If I understand you right.)

Comment: @pau yeah, I may have to bring it in. I'm hoping someone here will know something special about the I10 so I won't have to bring it in.

Comment: @msh210 Could you post some photos of the back seat area, that might help us to point out where it ought to be... Ideally include one with the seat base folded up, if it does?

Comment: @msh210 Does the leftmost seat in the photo lift forward too? I'd expect to see the center buckle adjacent to that seat's buckle, but can't see it in the photo - and there doesn't appear to be a space for it either... Was the center belt an optional extra? or only installed in certain trim levels?

Comment: @NickC Based on language I saw in the owner's manual, you're correct: the center belt _is_ an option.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell in the [owner's manual](http://www.customercare.hyundai.co.in/Upload/ownersMaual/grandi10-manual.pdf) (on page 52 of 360), the rear seat's center position uses a lap belt from the right (when viewed head on) to the left. This places the missing latch immediately beside the left seat's latch:

[image: rear center seat belt position on Hyundai i10]

Note carefully the caveat in that image, however: *if equipped*. You said you found the tongue, so you must have found that lap belt. Therefore, you'd expect to find its latch mate on the left side.

*However*, from the pictures in the OP, I'm not seeing the lap belt, so I'm dubious this i10 is *equipped* per the manual's caveat.

Comment: I had seen that in the manual and assumed that the parenthetical "if equipped" meant that in some cars the middle buckle is equipped (so to speak) with the "CENTER" mark and in others it's not. But maybe you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your car came with only TWO rear passengers setup (and belts-buckles as well) as a cheaper version? Cars with 3 rear passengers seats often have a horizontal belt for the center passenger which i cannot see in your pictures, so it might be completely missing out the center passenger setup.

Comment: The center seat's belt is in the picture.

Comment: @msh210 Is it? I'm expecting to see a lap belt per the OM, and I am not. Can you circle/highlight the center belt in your photos?

Comment: The centre belt is clearly visible in the photograph.  It's the only seatbelt that can be seen.  In certain jurisdictions (UK for example), a "lap belt" is no longer legal and all rear belts must be three point minimum.  I suspect they've simply forgotten to install it at the factory although I would suggest looking under the other seat cushion.